# segmentation fault double pointer realloc

Tags: c

I've got a small part of simple code that keeps giving me segmentation fault each time I go through the realloc for loop in the second if statement.

```
  *x = (int**)realloc(*x,nNew*sizeof(int*));

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
      x[i] = (int*) realloc(x[i],nNew*sizeof(int));  // seg fault
```

I think that the memory allocation has been done correctly (apparently not) but I cannot find the error.In the first if statement (where I de-allocate memory) it works correctly.

Sorry for the bad format.

```
void update(int **x,int n,int nNew)
{
   int  temp;    

   if(n>nNew)
   {
     *x = (int **) realloc(*x,nNew*sizeof(int*));

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       *(x+i) =(int *) realloc(x[i],nNew*sizeof(int));

     printf("temp %d",x[nNew-1][nNew-1]);
   }

   else if(n<nNew)
   {
      temp = x[n-1][n-1];

     *x = (int**)realloc(*x,nNew*sizeof(int*));

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
       x[i] = (int*) realloc(x[i],nNew*sizeof(int));   // seg fault

     printf("temp %d",**temp);
     for(int i=n;i<(nNew);i++)
     {
        for(int j=n;j<(nNew);j++)
          x[i][j] = temp;
     }
   }
} 

int main()
{
  int nNew = 9;
  int n = 8;

  int **x = (int **) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    x[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int)); 


  int count=0 ;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
     count ++;
     for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
       x[i][j] = count;
  } 

  update(x,n,nNew);

  for(int i=0;i<nNew;i++)
    free(x[i]);
  free(x);

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `temp` is uninitialized but you dereference it

Comment: the realloc is totally messed up too, `*x` is an `int *`

Comment: Why `int ** temp`, `int temp` is enough, all your cast seems broken. Everything looks weird, can we have the allocation of x before you call update to unterstand what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Is `x` an array of pointers to a buffer of  integers that was previously allocated by `malloc`? The return of `realloc` to see if it worked needs to be added.

Comment: int *ptr is a pointer to an int data. int **ptr is a pointer to the pointer pointing to an int data. realloc() returns a pointer to the allocated memory. so you should receive it with just a pointer instead of  casting to a pointer to pointer. Second thing, any non static variable declared inside a { } braces has scope only inside it. so your temp declared in the if part is not available in the else part.

Comment: Don't just say "*Sorry for the bad format*", fix the indentation.

Comment: agree @melpomene, anyway I changed it for him ... and us

Comment: This also has buffer overruns when growing the array because `malloc` isn't used to allocate new storage before it's being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reallocating what you think you are.

When you do this:

```
*x = (int**)realloc(*x,nNew*sizeof(int*));
```

for(int i=0;i

Since `x` has type `int **`, `*x` has type `int *`.  Also, `*x` is the same as `x[0]`.  So you're not reallocating the array of pointers on the first line but the first array of `int`.  You need to call `realloc` on the original pointer, *and* you need to pass the address of that pointer so that the change is visible in the calling program.

Then for the reallocation of the individual arrays, you need to call `realloc` on the original `n` to grow or shrink them, then either `free` the extra rows if growing or `malloc` the newly added rows.  In the growing case you want to `realloc` the array of pointers fisrt, and in the shrinking case you want to do that last.

So after those changes your `update` function should look like this:

```
void update(int ***x, int n, int nNew)
{
    if(n>nNew) {
        // shrink each row to be kept
        for(int i=0;i<nNew;i++)
           (*x)[i] = realloc((*x)[i],nNew*sizeof(int));

        // free the extra rows
        for(int i=nNew;i<n;i++)
            free((*x)[i]);

        // shrink the list of rows
        *x = realloc(*x,nNew*sizeof(int*));

    } else if(n<nNew) {
        // grow the list of rows
        *x = realloc(*x,nNew*sizeof(int*));

        // grow the existing rows
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            (*x)[i] = realloc((*x)[i],nNew*sizeof(int));

        // create the new rows
        for(int i=n;i<nNew;i++)
            (*x)[i] = malloc(nNew*sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
update(&x,n,nNew);
```